# Verifying the formula $\partial h(f\otimes\bar{c}) =(-1)^{n-q}(\delta f\otimes\bar{c})+h(f\otimes\partial\bar{c})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Spanier AT, it says that

> If $C$ and $C'$ are chain complexes and $G$ and $G'$ are paired to $G''$ by $\varphi$, there is a functorial homomorphism
> $$h:Hom(C',G)\otimes (C\otimes C'\otimes G')\to C\otimes G''$$
> such that $h(f\otimes(c\otimes c'\otimes g')) =c\otimes\varphi(\langle f,c'\rangle\otimes g')$ where $\langle f,c'\rangle$ denotes $f(c')$ if $\deg f =\deg c'$ and $0$ otherwise. Then for $f\in Hom(C_q',G)$ and $\bar{c}\in (C\otimes C')_n\otimes G'$
> $$\partial h(f\otimes\bar{c}) =(-1)^{n-q}(\delta f\otimes\bar{c})+h(f\otimes\partial\bar{c})$$

How can I get that formula? I searched formulas in the textbook and there's one thing somewhat close to the formula. The the boundary operator $\partial$ for tensor of two chain complexes. But in this case, it's $C\otimes G''$. Could you help?